# MVC postback in Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback

I have a table in MVC

```
@if (Model._OutReachEventList != null && Model._OutReachEventList.Count > 0)
            {
                WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model._OutReachEventList, canSort: true,  canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);


                @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "gridtbl" },
        tableStyle: "table",
        headerStyle: "table-header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alternating-row",
        rowStyle: "row-style",
        columns:
            grid.Columns(
                //grid.Column("", "SNo", format: item => item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1 + Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(grid.TotalRowCount / grid.PageCount) / grid.RowsPerPage) * grid.RowsPerPage * grid.PageIndex),
                grid.Column("EventDate", "Date Of Start", format: @<text><span>@Convert.ToDateTime(item.EventDate).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")</span></text>, style: "datewidth"),
                grid.Column("EventDateTo", "Date Of End", format: @<text><span>@Convert.ToDateTime(item.EventDateTo).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")</span></text>, style: "datewidth"),

                     grid.Column("EventTypeId", "Program Nature", format: @<text><span>
                        @if (item.EventTypeId != null && item.EventTypeId > 0)
                        {
                            @Model.EventTypeList.Where(x => x.Id == item.EventTypeId).FirstOrDefault().Name
                        }
                    </span></text>),
                    grid.Column("Name", "Title", format: @<text><span>@item.Name</span></text>, style: "namewidth"),

                    grid.Column("SchoolName", "Institution", format: @<text><span>@item.SchoolName</span></text>, style: "namewidth"),
                    grid.Column("AreaId", "Area", format: @<text><span>
                        @if (item.AreaId != null && item.AreaId != 0)
                        {
                            @Model.AreaList.Where(x => x.Id == item.AreaId).FirstOrDefault().Name
                        }

                    </span></text>))}
```

Now I want to Add a new Column to delete the row, I have added the Column but when I click on that column the page doesn't postback

This is how I have added the Column

```
   grid.Column("Del", "Delete", format: @<text><span>
                                                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "OutReach", FormMethod.Get, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "addethinicty" }))
                                                                    {
                                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                                                    }


                    </span></text>)
```

When I click on the Delete Column nothing happens, but If I take this Delete Code and place it outside of table Scope than it postback fine.

Please anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your form, because the button is a Submit button, and your form is suppose to act for Get method. I believe It should be FormMethod.Post

Comment: I changed FormMethod.Get to FormMethod.Post, even this doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I reference https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040139/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC and got your issue to work

Create the tables and data:

```
USE [Breaz]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster]    Script Date: 5/1/2017 3:33:56 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster](
    [MeetingId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MeetingName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Format] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.tblMeetingMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MeetingId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (1, N'Operational', N'Audt', N'Mumbai')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (2, N'HR', N'Audt', N'Mumbai')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (3, N'LifeScience', N'Audt', N'Dehradun')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (4, N'ITRetails', N'Functional', N'Dehradun')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (6, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (7, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (8, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (9, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (10, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (11, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (12, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (13, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (14, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (15, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (16, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (17, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (18, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (19, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (20, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (21, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (22, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (23, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] ([MeetingId], [MeetingName], [Format], [Location]) VALUES (24, N'repeat', N'repeat', N'repeate')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblMeetingMaster] OFF
GO
```

Create these classes:

```
public class Meeting
{
    [Key]
    public int MeetingId { get; set; }
    public string MeetingName { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

public class DataAccessLayer : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Meeting> MeetingMaster { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Meeting>().ToTable("tblMeetingMaster");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class MeetingVM
{
    public Meeting MeetingObj { get; set; }//contains single meeting details
    public List<Meeting> MeetingsObj { get; set; }//list of meeting
    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            if (MeetingsObj.Count > 0)
            {
                return "block";
            }
            else
            { return "none"; }
        }
    }//This will help us to handle the view logic
}
```

In the web.config connectionsStrings element , I added the following, you can add something similar.

```
<add name="DataAccessLayer" 
connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Breaz;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteMeeting(Meeting objMeeting)
    {
        MeetingVM obj = new MeetingVM();
        DataAccessLayer objDAL = new DataAccessLayer();
        objDAL.MeetingMaster.RemoveRange
        (objDAL.MeetingMaster.Where(c => c.MeetingId == objMeeting.MeetingId));
        objDAL.SaveChanges();
        obj.MeetingsObj = objDAL.MeetingMaster.ToList<Meeting>();
        return View(obj);
    }

    public ActionResult Index61()
    {
        DataAccessLayer objDAL = new DataAccessLayer();
        MeetingVM objMeetingVM = new MeetingVM();
        objMeetingVM.MeetingsObj = new List<Meeting>();
        objMeetingVM.MeetingsObj = objDAL.MeetingMaster.ToList<Meeting>();
        return View(objMeetingVM);
    }

    //I use Index60, you should use Index or what the RouteConfig points to
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index60(DDLModel ddlModel)
    {
        //BreazEntities16 for you should be the item that you had copied to the clipboard
        //before, or check the aDropDown.Context.cs file
        using (BreazEntities16 entity = new BreazEntities16())
        {
            //modify the tableId of table2
            entity.table2.Attach(ddlModel.table2);
            entity.Entry(ddlModel.table2).Property(x => x.table1Id).IsModified = true;
            entity.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            entity.SaveChanges();  //tableid changes, not table2Desc
        }

        return View(ddlModel);
    }
```

My view looks like this:

```
@model Testy20161006.Models.MeetingVM
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function DeleteME(id) {
            //debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/DeleteMeeting',
                data: {
                    MeetingId: id
                }
            }); //e
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="exportWebGrid" action="Meeting/ExportHeade" method="post">
        <div name="webView" style="display:@Model.Status">
            @{
                WebGrid objWebGrid = new WebGrid(Model.MeetingsObj, rowsPerPage: 5, canPage: true);
            }
            @objWebGrid.GetHtml(
       tableStyle: "Grid-table",
       headerStyle: "Grid-Header",
       alternatingRowStyle: "Grid-alt",
       selectedRowStyle: "Grid-selected",
       rowStyle: "Grid-rowstyle",
       footerStyle: "Grid-Footer",
       mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, //Specifies flags that describe the methods that are provided for moving between the pages of a WebGrid instance. source msdn.microsoft.com
    columns:
       objWebGrid.Columns
       (
           objWebGrid.Column(columnName: "MeetingID", header: "Meeting ID"),
           objWebGrid.Column(columnName: "MeetingName", header: "Name of Meeting"),
           objWebGrid.Column(columnName: "Format", header: "Name of Fomat"),
           objWebGrid.Column(columnName: "Location", header: "Location at"),
           objWebGrid.Column(format: @<text><a href=""
                                               onclick="DeleteME('@item.MeetingID')">Delete</a></text>)
        )
 )
        </div>
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Export to Excel" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used <a> tag and now it is posting back. Thanks